# Make a bullet inflict a debuff in TModLoader

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a bullet in TModLoader, that gives enemies it hits the "Chilled" debuff. From the research I've done, this code should work. Whenever I run it, it gives me the error "*IceShot.HitNPC: No suitable method found to override.*" Thanks!

```
using Terraria;
using Terraria.ID;
using Terraria.ModLoader;

namespace Tweaks.Items
{
    public class IceShot : ModItem
    {
        public override void SetStaticDefaults()
        {
            DisplayName.SetDefault("Ice Shot");
            Tooltip.SetDefault("Inflicts the \"Chilled\" debuff");
        }

        public override void SetDefaults()
        {
            item.damage = 9;
            item.ranged = true;
            item.width = 8;
            item.height = 8;
            item.maxStack = 999;
            item.consumable = true;
            item.knockBack = 1.5f;
            item.value = 10;
            item.rare = ItemRarityID.Green;
            item.shoot = ModContent.ProjectileType<IceShotProjectile>();
            item.shootSpeed = 16f;
            item.ammo = AmmoID.Bullet;
        }

        public override void OnHitNPC(NPC target, int damage, float knockback, bool crit)
        {
            target.AddBuff(46, 180, false);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Don't know anything about TModLoader, but the error and your code have different function names. Not sure if that's your problem though.

Comment: Have you asked on the Terraria Forums?

Comment: Have you asked on the Terraria Forums? - Yeah, still no reply

Answer (score 1):

I know that I'm answering this question really late, but this fix is really simple. You are missing the `Player player` parameter.

Instead of this:

```
public override void OnHitNPC(NPC target, int damage, float knockback, bool crit) {
    target.AddBuff(46, 180, false);
}
```

Put this:

```
public override void OnHitNPC(Player player, NPC target, int damage, float knockback, bool crit) {
    target.AddBuff(BuffID.Chilled, 180, false);
}
```

I added the missing parameter, and I also changed the first parameter of `target.AddBuff()` from 46 to `BuffID.Chilled`, because it improves readability.

If the error goes away but the target isn't inflicted with `Chilled`, then move this code to your `IceShotProjectile.cs` file.